# MySQL & PHPMyadmin - cannot create relation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

Ok, so I have a database with a number of tables, but I have an issue with two in particular. One is called "asset", and structure is thus:

```
`assetid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`typeid` varchar(2),
`make` varchar(40),
`model` varchar(40),
`serno` varchar(40),
`opsys` varchar(40),
`ownerid` varchar(4)L,
`locid` varchar(4),
`purdate` date,
`insdate` date,
`remdate` date,
`dispdate` date,
`techid` varchar(3)
```

The other is called "supplier":

```
`suppid` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`suppname` varchar(40),
`assetid` varchar(5),
`lastpurdate` date,
```

In "asset" my PK is assetID.  In supplier, I originally had a PK as suppid and assetid.  However I could not create a relation linking supplier.assetid to asset.assetid.  I was not allowed to do so in PHPMyAdmin, so I deleted assetid from supplier, and added suppid to asset.  I want to make suppid a foreign key in asset, but when I try to do so I get this:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`assettracker`.`#sql-15c4_672`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-15c4_672_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`suppid`) REFERENCES `supplier` (`suppid`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Why am I not allowed to do this?

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix this?  Suppid is a primary key in supplier (or at least it should be).

Comment: Could you add the command you're trying to run to add the new key?

Comment: I'm not using a command - I am using the "Relation View" control panel in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Does that work?